# Implementing smartbanner.js or another lib

Tags: vue.js, web, smartbanner

Have you integrated this library with Vue 2? Do you happen to know better ways to implement this?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/smartbanner.js?amp=1

I try to implement this library according to instructions

Added to my index.html

```
<meta name="smartbanner:title" content="Smart Application">
<meta name="smartbanner:author" content="SmartBanner Contributors">
<meta name="smartbanner:price" content="FREE">
<meta name="smartbanner:price-suffix-apple" content=" - On the App Store">
<meta name="smartbanner:price-suffix-google" content=" - In Google Play">
<meta name="smartbanner:icon-apple" content="https://url/to/apple-store-icon.png">
<meta name="smartbanner:icon-google" content="https://url/to/google-play-icon.png">
<meta name="smartbanner:button" content="VIEW">
<meta name="smartbanner:button-url-apple" content="https://ios/application-url">
<meta name="smartbanner:button-url-google" content="https://android/application-url">
<meta name="smartbanner:enabled-platforms" content="android,ios">
<meta name="smartbanner:close-label" content="Close">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/smartbanner.js/dist/smartbanner.min.css">
<script src="node_modules/smartbanner.js/dist/smartbanner.min.js"></script>
```

to tag  in my index.html file on project and it dont work. I dont see banner.

Comment: "dont work" isn't a technical description of a problem.  you need a better description of what is wrong.  error? bug? unexpected behavior?  what were your steps for installing?  did you `npm install` the library?  where exactly in `index.html` are your link and script tags? are you viewing the page on desktop or mobile?  all these things could affect the correctness of the library.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So, I added code from question to my index.html. Problem I dont see banner without any errors.

Comment: I have errors in my console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'